# Login intermittently hangs at Group Policy Processing

Tags: group-policy, login

We are having intermittent login issues where the login process would get stuck somewhere in the Group Policy Processing section

(During this time the C:\WIndows\debug group policy log does not mention anything...it seems like its just hanging on the next step.)

...it will just sit there until it times out or eventually processes.

Rebooting the machine seems to fix this issue temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a similar situation back in the days, when we had a GPO set up to redirect "My Documents" from the local drive, to a network folder (UNC path). Once the GPO was applied, on the next login, Windows would take minutes to process the GPO as it was copying all the files from the local "My Documents" to the network folder. Sometimes, the GPO would fail to apply, because the path limit exceeded 255 characters, and Windows wasn't able to process it. That error was listed as an event in the Event Viewer. And after that, every time the user would log back in, the GPO would run again (copying files from the local drive to the network folder) and it would take minutes for the session to open.

All this to say that one of your GPO might be hanging or generating errors in the Event Viewer, so you should investigate it and see if you can find any errors, warnings, etc. between the time you tried to log in, and the time the session opened.

Also, try to review any recent changes to your GPOs.

Comment: Thanks for responding.

It's weird because the only GPO related error that I see in error logs is that the login took X amount of seconds to log in ... usually extremely high (3500s+) with no other specific GPO Errors. 

RDP into affected machines hang and even trying to remotely connect to the event viewer of affected machines during this time results in a "RPC Server is unavailable" error.

Comment: Are there more details in that "RPC Server is unavailable" error? An error code, a CLSID, etc. that could be used to investigate what call is failing. It's possible that one of the setting applied via GPO starts a RPC call to a server, the call ends up timing out and that would explain the issue you're facing.